# No Google fonts working in Google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

Here is the [link](https://branard.com/index.php?option=com_brands&view=detail&id=16&Itemid=102)

If you click the squares within the black section they will change the font of the word to the left. All of the fonts are Google fonts but non of them are working in Google Chrome. I've searched the internet with no solution. All other browsers it is working fine.

Comment: Google Chrome has the most problems loading their own fonts. It's ridiculous.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are getting an error message that explains a bit more. Try pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, then click on the `Console` tab. You'll see the error message

> [blocked] The page at https://branard.com/index.php?option=com_brands&view=detail&id=16&Itemid=102 ran insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Erica+One|Monda|Sacramento|Oleo+Script+Swash+Caps|Text+Me+One|Seymour+One|Cagliostro|Qwigley.

Chrome now displays this message when you fetch insecure content via HTTP when the main page is running HTTPS.

It should just be a matter of changing the font url from `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css` to `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css` to secure this link.

Comment: It’s a little safer to just omit the `http:` part from the URL, thereby defaulting the protocol to the protocol of the page itself.

Comment: Thank you. I had to ask this question for my developers.

Comment: It's amazing what one stinkin' character can do to ruin your code. +1, thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature of the browser that blocks `http` content included from a host page served via `https`. The fix is simple: just remove the protocol from all resource URLs (scripts, stylesheets, etc.). In your case, the URL to the fonts CSS becomes

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/css…
```

Notice that the URL has no `http` or `https`.

Comment: I wish people would have the nous to comment when downvoting. Looks like a legitimate solution to me, although beware of [the pitfalls](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/04/18/protocol-relative-urls/).